# File extension is striped when storing a specific filename in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have three files:
1. moodsLogo.jpg
2. Copy of (images').jpg
3. Moods logo (Custom).jpg

and I have the following code:

```
// (..) some code here
$fileName     = valid_filename($_FILES[ 'Filedata' ][ 'name' ]);
$bl->updateFieldValue("tableName","columnName",$fileName, $id);

function valid_filename($filename)
{
    $filename = str_replace(" ", "_", $filename);
    $pattern = "/[^[a-z0-9._-]/";
    return preg_replace($pattern, "", strtolower($filename));
}
```

And the SQL looks like this:

```
  public function updateFieldValue($table,$column,$value, $id)
  {
    $result = parent::updateRow($table,$column, $value, $id);  
    return $result;
  }

  public function updateRow($table,$column, $value, $id)
  {
    $sql = "UPDATE $table SET $column = '$value' WHERE id = $id";
    $this->query($sql);
    return $this->query_result;    
  }
```

Now, processing file 1 and 2 works fine. In my DB I can see the entire filename with the extension.

But when I process file 3, the filename is either stored as `moods_logo_custom.jp` or `moods_logo_custom.`. I've even tried using '`Copy of (Custom).jpg`' and it works fine.

An echo before calling the query, shows that $filename is correct.

So what on earth makes THAT specific filename fale ? Why can't I store the entire filename in DB?

Comment: It is the longest name, and it's getting cut off... I'd start looking at the field width of the field you're storing it into.

Comment: What does your schema look like? It's possible that the updated value is being truncated because it's longer than the length specified in the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you database schema to see if the field (referenced in you code as `$column`) on table `$table` is set to something like:

```
column_name VARCHAR(20)
```

Or possibly:

```
column_name CHAR(20)
```

You might need to `ALTER` the table(s) to allow for longer strings.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the field length of the field you are storing the name in?
The value `moods_logo_custom.jp` is 20 chars in length, or is this just coincidence?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a SQL command that will expand the width of your column to hold longer strings, because this seems to be the problem you're having.

```
ALTER TABLE __table__ MODIFY COLUMN __column__ VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT ""
```

Hope this works out for you!